# How to update RecyclerView when use retrofit?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

i want to update RecyclerView when item removed but i dont' have idea to solve, i try to use notifydatasetchanged() but it don't work.

API Interface

```
interface RetrofitService {
    @GET("/")
    suspend fun getAllItem() : Response<List<Item>>

    @POST("/delete")
    suspend fun deleteItem(@Body item :Item) : Response<Item>
```

class Repository

```
class ItemRepository(private val retrofitService: RetrofitService) {
    suspend fun getAllItem() = retrofitService.getAllItem()

    suspend fun deleteItem(item : Item) = retrofitService.deleteItem(item)
}
```

in ViewModel, i handle result by two function(handleItemResponse and handleListItemResponse)

```
class ItemViewModel(private val itemRepository: ItemRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val itemResponse: MutableLiveData<Resource<Item>> = MutableLiveData()

    val listItemResponse : MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Item>>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getItemResponse() = viewModelScope.launch {
        val response : Response<List<Item>> = itemRepository.getAllItem()
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            listItemResponse.postValue(handleListItemResponse(response))
        }
    }
    fun deleteItem(item: Item) = viewModelScope.launch {
        val response = itemRepository.deleteItem(item)
        itemResponse.postValue(handleItemResponse(response))
    }
    private fun handleItemResponse(response: Response<Item>): Resource<Item> {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body()?.let { resultResponse ->
                return Resource.Success(resultResponse)
            }
        }
        return Resource.Error(response.message())
    }
    private fun handleListItemResponse(response: Response<List<Item>>): Resource<List<Item>> {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body()?.let { resultResponse ->
                return Resource.Success(resultResponse)
            }
        }
        return Resource.Error(response.message())
    }
}
```

and class Resource to logging result

```
sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data:T?=null,
    val messaage : String? = null
) {
    class Success<T>(data:T) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(messaage: String,data:T? = null) : Resource<T>(data,messaage)
    class Loading<T> : Resource<T>()
}
```

in Fragment , i use ViewModel like this

```
viewModel.listItemResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when (it) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"All Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    it.data?.let { itemReponse ->
                        listItem = itemReponse
                        adapter.setNotes(listItem)
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    it.messaage?.let { msg ->
                        Log.e("AAA","ERR:$msg ")
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        viewModel.getItemResponse()
    }
```

in Adapter , i getList by function setNotes

```
fun setNotes(items:List<Item>){
            this.items = items
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

and function to delete item

```
 private val onItemDelete:(Item)->Unit ={ item  ->
        viewModel.itemResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when (it) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    it.data?.let {  
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Delete successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    it.messaage?.let { msg ->
                        Toast.makeText(context," \"ERR:$msg \"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        viewModel.deleteItem(item)
    }
```

**My english not well , so i hope you sympathize and help me, have a nice day,everyone!**

I fixed it, i put it for anyone face same my problem.

```
private val onItemDelete:(Int)->Unit ={ pos  ->
        viewModel.itemResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when (it) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    it.data?.let {  
                        listItem.removeAt(pos)
                        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos)
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    it.messaage?.let { msg ->
                        Toast.makeText(context," \"ERR:$msg \"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        viewModel.deleteItem(listItem[pos])
    }
```

just callback position of item then get it in fragment.

Comment: How you are removing the item from the `recycler view` .  According to return type of `deleteItem` it only returns the deleted item and not the updated list with all remaining  item

Comment: i just add it above.so how can i solve it? i pass a object to fragment when clicked , so i can't get position of item to notify.

Comment: Can you confirm this?
1. You are getting the data properly and can show the data is recycler view.
2. Your delete code deletes the data in the server and sends you the updated list.

Comment: it just not updated list , i can show list data is RecyclerView and delete it, but i have to destroy fragment then re create , then it loading new list.

Comment: `listItem.remove(item)` and then `notifyDataSetChanged()`  add this in your `onItemDelete` just before delete successful toast. You are not removing the item from your list while you have remove it from api , that is why on re-opening fragment you call the api again the get the updated list